# Display google search result links using html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, google-chrome-extension, google-search

I am building a simple chrome extension using HTML and js which

1. Takes URL of the current page
2. Converts it to google search string
3. Display links of all the results on the first page as an unordered list in the extension box.

I am stuck on the 3rd step.
I understand that this may be done using Beautiful Soup in Python but don't know how to implement it using JS.
On doing `console.log(html)`, I am getting an empty string, but the same code works on any other html page.

HTML code -

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Top 5 searches from google</h1>
    <button id="checkPage">Click!</button>
    <ul>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS code -

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var checkPageButton = document.getElementById('checkPage');
  checkPageButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, tabs => {
      let myUrl = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='+tabs[0].url;
      fetch(myUrl, {mode: 'no-cors'}).then(function (response) {
      console.log(response)
      console.log(response.text())
      return response.text();
    }).then(function (html) {
      console.log(html)
      var parser = new DOMParser();
      var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
      console.log(doc)
      var h3Elements = doc.getElementsByTagName("h3");
      console.log(h3Elements);
    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
    });
    });
  }, false);
}, false);
```

Comment: Use `fetch(url)` and `DOMParser` to parse the html. There should be many examples of using both as it's a very popular task. Note that the html response will be simplified because `fetch` doesn't run page scripts. You can see the response's contents in devtools. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I have a parsedHtml using `parser.parseFromString(response, 'text/html')`. But if I do `parsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("h3")`, I get empty collection.

Comment: Inspect and beautify the actual html response in devtools and see what it contains.

Comment: parsedHtml contains `[object Promise]` inside body tags.

Comment: That's not how you inspect network response in devtools, see tutorials.

Comment: In the Networks tab, I can see my JS and HTML files and on clicking on response, the content of both the files is visible. However I am not sure about how to see parsedHTML in it. Kindly help me.

Comment: https://puu.sh/Hj98o/9040fb8cc8.png See tutorials on using devtools for more info.

Comment: I think the problem is that I am giving response to `parseFromString` function instead of some html input where response has been defined as `let response = fetch(myUrl, {mode: 'no-cors'})`. But I don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: Like I suggested, see tutorials/examples on how to use `fetch`.